# Can't load data from database using Remix web framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, remix.run

I am pretty new to Remix and React and I'm trying to follow the `Databases` section of the [Data Loading](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/guides/data-loading) documentation page for Remix as an example. Below is the code I am using.

**data.server.tsx**
This is the class I use to connect to a PostgreSQL database.

```
import pkg from 'pg';
const { Client } = pkg;

class DB {
    client: Client;

    async getData () {
        return new Promise (async (resolve, reject) =>
        {
            var query = "select * from my_table";
            await this.client.query (query)
                .then ((result) =>
                {
                    if (result.rows.length == 0)
                        reject ('no results');

                    var result_data = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++)
                        result_data [result.rows [i].k] = result.rows [i].v;

                    resolve (result_data);
                })
                .catch ((error) => { reject (error); });
        });
    }

    constructor () {
        this.client = new Client ({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 5432, database: 'my_db', user: 'my_user', password: 'my_pw' });
    }

    async connect () {
        await this.client.connect ();
    }
}

const db_client = new DB ();
async function connect () {
    await db_client.connect ();
}
connect ();

export { db_client };
```

**component.tsx**
This is the component and loader.

```
import { db_client } from "./data.server.tsx";
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
import type { LoaderFunctionArgs } from "@remix-run/node";


export async function loader({
  request,
}: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
    const data = await db_client.getData ();
    console.log ('server data: ', data);
    return json(data);
}

function Component ()
{
    const data = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
    console.log ('client data: ', data);

    return (
        <div>Where the data would be displayed.</div>
    );
}
```

**Results:**

In the terminal where the server messages are displayed I see:

```
server data:  [
  keya: 'Value A',
  keyb: 'Value B',
  keyc: 'Value C'
]
```

But in the browser console I see:

```
client data: []
```

The loader definitely has the data because it prints it to the screen, but it returns an empty array. I have tried adding timestamps to the messages and I can see that the loader is called before the component is rendered.

Why doesn't the client receive the data?

Comment: You are using a lot of `async` declared functions and never `await`-ing them to settle... are you sure this code is as asynchronous as you think? Have you done any debugging in the `DB` class code?

Comment: @DrewReese I was not `await`-ing my original call to `connect()`, but fixing that did not fix the problem. The problem would have been really hard to find just by looking through the code. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a data type error. In my `getData()` function, I was filling the array of result data with the following code:

```
var result_data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++)
    result_data [result.rows [i].k] = result.rows [i].v;
```

This initializes an empty array and then sets the keys as if it were an object. It is possible to create an object that way, but things like the `length` property won't work correctly. `console.log()` was able to print all of the data to the screen from the loader. However, when it was sent to `json()`, it was interpreted as an empty array and returned only `[]`.

The solution was to initialize the result data like this:

```
var result_data = {};
```